# Nifi SSL configuration on handleHttpRequest

Tags: apache-nifi

We configured https authentication by using NifiToolKit on Nifi(1.3).
We have a requirement of having https enabled for the rest end points created using - (HandleHTTPRequest -> CustomProcessors -> HandleHTTPResponse).

Configured **SSL context service** using the same keystore,truststore properties that were **generated** by the NifiToolkit previously.

Currently i am running Nifi on port 9443 and handleHTTPRequest on 56661.

When i hit the URL with port 56661 from the client , i am getting **SSL error** even after passing the certificate and the keycode.

```
import requests
requests.port('https://IPADDRESS:56661/sample',verify='PATH/certificate.pem',json= {})
```

Can anyone help me on this.. Thanks in advance..
Below is the link which i referred for https configuration on nifi.

https://bryanbende.com/development/2016/08/17/apache-nifi-1-0-0-authorization-and-multi-tenancy

Comment: Please include the relevant portions of the stacktrace in `$NIFI_HOME/logs/nifi-app.log`. The code you included also hits port 9443, not 56661.

Comment: I have included 56661 as well and getting the same error

Comment: please provide the full error message. and also i guess this question more about python code and not to nifi configuration...

Comment: Can you access the HTTPS endpoint via a browser or CURL? That will help narrow down where the encryption is not working as expected.